# Dynamic Array implementation in C++

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-memory-allocation, definition, member-functions

I am trying to implement Dynamic Array using C++. However, my `resize()` function seem to not work properly. There are no errors or warnings. I did some research and tried to look at other implementations found on the internet but was unable to fix the issue. I put my code below.

```
#include <iostream>

class Array
{
private:
    int* arr;
    int size = 0;
    int capacity = 1;

public:
    Array() { arr = new int[capacity]; }

    Array(int capacity)
        :
        capacity(capacity)
    {
        arr = new int[capacity];
    }

    int length() const { return size; }

    bool is_empty() const { return (length() == 0); }

    int get(int index) const { return arr[index]; }

    void set(int index, int value) { arr[index] = value; }

    void resize()
    {
        capacity *= 2;
        int* temp = new int[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { temp[i] = arr[i]; }
        delete[] arr;
        arr = temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) { arr[i] = 0; }
    }

    void add(int value)
    {
        if (size + 1 >= capacity) { resize(); }
        arr[size++] = value;
    }

    void remove(int index)
    {
        for (int i = index; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }
        size--;
    }

    int& operator[](int index)
    {
        return arr[index];
    }
};

int main()
{
    Array array;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        array.add(i + 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << array.get(i) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\t' << array.length() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The code outputs:

```
0 0 0 4 5   5
```

But I expect it to output:

```
1 2 3 4 5   5
```

Comment: Why do you want to zero out the allocated capacity past `size`? Just leave it uninitialized and write checks in your get methods to ensure they're never read before they've been written to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `resize` method you copied over the existing elements from `arr`

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { temp[i] = arr[i]; }
```

But then later you `0` all of the elements out, effectively clearing the previous data

```
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) { arr[i] = 0; }
```

Instead you likely just want to `0` the trailing new elements

```
for (int i = size; i < capacity; ++i) { arr[i] = 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

This loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) { arr[i] = 0; }
```

is incorrect. It sets the first size elements to 0.

In fact this loop is redundant. Instead of this loop you could just write in the statement where the memory is allocated like

```
int* temp = new int[capacity]();
```

Also the definition of the function `add()` is incorrect. It should look like:

```
void add(int value)
{
    if (size == capacity) { resize(); }
    arr[size++] = value;
}
```

You need to define explicitly the destructor. For example

```
~Array()
{
    delete []arr;
}
```

Also you need either to define explicitly a copy constructor and the copy assignment operator or define them as deleted. For example

```
Array( const Array & ) = delete;
Array & operator =( const Array & ) = delete;
```

Otherwise using these member functions can result in undefined behavior.

Comment: `if (size + 1 >= capacity) { resize(); }` is not wrong; it resizes before the current add operation would make the arr full. And `if (size == capacity) { resize(); }` resizes if the last add operation has made the arr full. Just different choice of timing.